Unable to get recapcha to work - error message is mostly of screen
Iam unable to get recaptcha to work. There is an error message displayed but it is mostly off screen to the bottom right.
I have followed the setup instructions correctly and am working on an upgrade with visual code and codepen. I am not a developer I am currently teaching myself to program for something to do! I will use the site when it's finished. Does the website have to be hosted for recapcha to work?
Can the error message be set to display somewhere else? I'm using chrome!


It's even comfusing to discover where captcha keys are stored. No straight forward links.

You can manage (create, edit, delete) your reCAPTCHA keys in the Cloud Console.
https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha
From your screenshot it looks like the error is related to an unexpected domain. Since you are serving the site locally then I would update the "Domain list" to include localhost.
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website
Once you deploy your site you can update this domain list to reflect whichever domains and subdomains you would like to protect with this reCAPTCHA key.
